# Desplegar menú al pasar mouse

Tags: c#, wpf

tengo una menú desplegable con una hamburguesa que se esconde  al dar clic

al dar clic en la flecha  esconde el menú y muestra la hamburguesa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y muestra el menú minimizado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que necesito es que este menú no se esconda al darle clic si no que eso pase al pasar el mouse como puedo disparar esa acción con el hover

**xaml**

```
<Button x:Name="ButtonOpenMenu" Height="48" Width="55" Margin="0,5,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionMiniAccentButton}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FF31577E" Click="ButtonOpenMenu_Click" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
<Button.RenderTransform>
<TransformGroup>
<ScaleTransform/>
<SkewTransform/>
<RotateTransform Angle="0.849"/>
<TranslateTransform/>
</TransformGroup>
</Button.RenderTransform>
<materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Menu" Width="25" Height="25" Foreground="orange"/>
</Button>

<Button x:Name="ButtonCloseMenu" Visibility="Collapsed" Height="60" Width="60" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionMiniAccentButton}" Background="{x:Null}"BorderBrush{x:Null}"Foreground="#FF31577E"Click="ButtonCloseMenu_Click">
<materialDesign:PackIconKind="ArrowLeft"Width="25"Height="25"Foreground=</Button>
```

**cs**

```
 private void MoveCursorMenu(int index)
        {
            TransitioningContentSlide.OnApplyTemplate();
            GridCursor.Margin = new Thickness(0, (10 + (60 * index)), 0, 0);
        }

        private void ButtonOpenMenu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonCloseMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            ButtonOpenMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            GridMain.Margin = new Thickness(210, 112, 10, 10);
            LabelInformativo.Margin = new Thickness(208, 72, 10, 0);

            //TransitioningContentSlides.OnApplyTemplate();
        }

        private void ButtonCloseMenu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonCloseMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            ButtonOpenMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;      
            GridMain.Margin = new Thickness(94, 112, 10, 10);
            LabelInformativo.Margin = new Thickness(90, 72, 10, 0);
                    }
    }
```

Comment: Creo que es muy importante que aclares que estas usando el pack de materialdesign para wpf.

Comment: Si, señor estoy usando el pack